# Spring Roo - automatic update

Tags: java, spring-roo

I've tried to use Roo. If I create a class using Roo and then modify it in the IDE, Roo finds the change and updates all aspects and so.

But If I create a class using IDE, Roo doesn't discover the newly created class at all :-(

Is there a command which has to be done, am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm going to check answers to my question and manage them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring Roo [annotations](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html-single/#architecture) triggers code generation.

```
@RooEntity
```

Entity methods like `persist`, `findById` etc.

```
@RooJavaBean
```

Generates mutators (getter/setters).

```
@RooToString
```

Generates `toString` method.
GWT scaffolding looks for `@RooEntity` classes.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, you have to wait a while till the file system watcher identifies a new class.

A refresh in the IDE might do the trick. If you are using eclipse, use STS with Roo add-on -- which is quite fast in detecting the changes.